# Longest Common Subsequence top-bottom

Tags: c++, output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int LCS(string x, string y , int n , int m)
{
  int t[n+1][m+1];
  for(int i=0;i<=n+1;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<=m+1;j++)
    {
        if(i==0 || j==0)
            t[i][j]=0;
    }
  for(int i=1;i<=n+1;i++)
    for(int j=1;j<=m+1;j++)
    {
        if(x[i-1]==y[j-1])
            t[i][j]=1+t[i-1][j-1];
        else
            t[i][j]=max(t[i-1][j],t[i][j-1]);
    }
  return t[n][m];
}

int main()
{
    string x;
    string y;
    cin>>x>>y;
    LCS(x,y,x.length(),y.length());
    return 0;
}
```

o/p=Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.342 s
Press any key to continue.

the o/p to the following code is always zero . idk why. plzz help . what wrong am I doing ?

Comment: If you search for "longest common subsequence c++" in your favorite search-engine you will find  many thousands of links, if not hundreds of thousands. Quite a few of them to questions here on Stack Overflow. In short, there are many tutorials and examples and answers to this question already.

Comment: As for your problem, it seems like it's independent of the assignment or exercise, and is probably because your `main` function does (unconditionally) do `return 0`. Do note that the returned value from `main` is by convention a *small* non-negative integer (in the range `0` to `255`, inclusive), and that anything but `0` is considered an error. In short: You never use the value that `LCS` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the o/p to the following code is always zero

because your *main* does :

> ```
> ...
> LCS(x,y,x.length(),y.length());
> return 0;
> ```

but you want :

```
...
return LCS(x,y,x.length(),y.length());
```

---

Out of that

> ```
>  int t[n+1][m+1];
> ```

is a variable length array, do not use them (see [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)) but array dynamically allocated in the heap, because the size are not known at compile time you can use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` and for instance replace

> ```
>  int t[n+1][m+1];
>  for(int i=0;i<=n+1;i++)
>    for(int j=0;j<=m+1;j++)
>    {
>        if(i==0 || j==0)
>            t[i][j]=0;
>    }
> ```

by

```
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> t(n+1);
  
  for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
    t[i].resize(m+1);
```

BTW your loops are wrong because the right tests are `i<=n`and `j<=m` everywhere

Comment: `std::array` is automatically allocated (i.e. on the stack). `std::vector` woule be for dynamic allocation.

Comment: The question is what you are talking about. If the OP wants runtime dimensions, then they cannot use `std::array`, because it's size is a compile-time constant, and it gets stored on the stack, with the data right inside itself. It is not allocated on the heap (unless one does something daft like allocating a pointer to an `std::array`, but even that still must have compile-time size).

Comment: @underscore_d ah yes damned

Comment: what changes should I do?

Comment: @aniketsagar I just edited my answer, you can use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`

Comment: can u edit code and post it. am not able to get what to do. am new to StackOverflow community.